# How to Upload Excel File to Sql database table in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, upload

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC currently developing this UploadExcel data to SQL table application in ASP.NET MVC. My issues is, I cannot able to collect the file in parameter Object (in formCollection) of Upload Action Method. Please help!!!

Because of that I cannot able to go into 'if Statments' its show file is `null`.

My action method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(FormCollection formCollection)
{
    var userList = new List<Employee_table>();
    if (Request != null)
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
            var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
            {
                ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
                var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
                for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                {
                    var user = new Employee_table();
                    user.Year = Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value);
                    user.Month = Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value);
                    user.Div_Code = Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Value);
                    user.Div_Name = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].ToString();
                    user.EMP_Code = Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 5].Value);
                    user.EMP_Name = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 6].ToString();
                    user.DESG_Code = Convert.ToInt32(workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 7].Value);
                    userList.Add(user);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    using (File_UploadEntities excelImportDBEntities = new File_UploadEntities())
    {
        foreach (var item in userList)
        {
            excelImportDBEntities.Employee_table.Add(item);
        }
        int result = excelImportDBEntities.SaveChanges();
        if (result > 0)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
    return View("Index");

}
```

My view:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {

        @*@Html.EditorFor(x => x.File_Name, new { @class = "Labelfor", style = "width: 20px; background-color: green;" }) <br />*@

    <div class="action-buttons">
        <input type="file" name="File" accept=".xls,.xlsx" id="btn-choose" />
        <input type="submit" name="Download" value="Download Template" formaction="Download" id="btn-download" class="btn btn-primary"/>

    </div>
        <br />

        <input type="submit" value="Upload Data" id="btn-Upload" formaction="FileUpload" class="btn btn-primary" />
    }
</div>
```

Web.Config:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="FileUpload" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\Local;Initial Catalog=File_Upload;Integrated Security=True " providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="File_UploadEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\Local;initial catalog=File_Upload;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The Excel file would be a MIME attachment (a multipart/format-data) in the request.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true  Each MIME starts on a new line with two dashes.  The Content-Type (a header) of a HTTP request has to match what is in the body (contents) or the request.  You are creating a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the `input` tag in your case `<input type="file" name="File" accept=".xls,.xlsx" id="btn-choose" />` has name `File` change the action method declaration accordingly:

```cs
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // Code below is used for test purpose
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~/"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
        file.SaveAs(path);       
    }

    // Put your code here...

    return View();
}
```

After that you don't need to use `HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["UploadedFile"];`. But if you still want to use this line for some reason it's necessary to change the `Request.Files["UploadedFile"]` to `Request.Files["file"]`, because using `name="File"` in the `input` tag definition.